# Script crashes when starting from .desktop file

Tags: bash, scripts, .desktop, openbox, gksudo

When I execute script from terminal by hand, it runs without problems:

```
gksudo /path/to/module.sh
```

But when I use .desktop file to run script on startup:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gksudo /path/to/module.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=module
Comment=module
```

It runs at first but then crashes.
Module basically is a infinite while loop, listening to process and if process is not running script runs command.

What can be a problem?

I'm using Lubuntu openbox

Script sample:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/modules/lib
EXECMOD="/path/to/module" # module is a C++ program
PNAME="module"

while [ : ]
do
    $EXECMOD

    ANS=$?
    if [ $ANS -eq 0 ]
        then
        break
    fi

    # Wait
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Hi notgiorgi, posted my answer. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Can you show us a minimal example of your script that reproduces the problem? What do you mean by "It runs at first but then crashes."? Does it run correctly but it stops after a while? Does it run the first time you try but not the second? Does the `gksu` dialog appear? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please answer my other questions as well? [Edit] your question and add the answers there. Also, the script you show will attempt to run `module` and stop the first time it launches it successfully. What is it that crashes? What are you expecting to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: This bash script should relaunch C++ program (module) if it stops running. Yes, it runs correctly and after a while crashes. gksudo dialog doesn't appear.

Comment: Removed my answer and my request(s) below it, since it is unclear if it works or not. No offence, but you could be a bit more communicative. It helps finding out if an answer works or not. Useful to others as well.

Comment: Actually, your answer a was helpful, which I stated. I cannot tell if it was 100% helpful, as my situation is not very straightforward.

Comment: @notgiorgi Well one small thing I've noticed there is that you have a line that is waiting to be completed `$EXECMOD`. Typically one wants to run and detach a program so that next lines of the script can be executed. Was your purpose here different ? Did you want the loop to wait till `$EXECMOD` exits ?